# number_format without change decimals count

Tags: php, twig

In twig template i use number_format. How i can don't change decimals count and change decimal point and thousands separator?

Example:

```
{% set number = 4.55 %}
{{ number|number_format(?, ',', ' ') }} // 4,55
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly it is not possible to do just with Twig. As a workaround you can set to some big value and trim ending zeros. Also you should check if it is not for example `100`.

As a dirty workaround you can use `replace` method.

```
{{ number|replace('.', '_')|replace(',', ' ')|replace('_', ',') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig supports [named arguments](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#named-arguments) as of 1.12. Use it this way:

```
{{ number|number_format(decimal_point=",", thousand_sep=" ") }}
```

Comment: Yeah, if argument is not defined it doesn't mean that system will not change the number of decimals -- the default value will be used.